# does browser automatically decode string which is encoded

Tags: url-encoding

Im passing following query string in browser which is encoded

`http://abc/PreviewSurveyFormDetails.jsp?issueType=7t7Jpz2Oa8b6V5iy%2b6c6205ScixWnhYzj0FEuG6M1AhAOxcRXWDwWQ%3d%3d`

While getting "issueType" in jsp page im getting decoded value
Following is the code

`String str=request.getParameter("issueType");`

> Does browser decode automatically?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: plz help some one thanks